# JS: Как получить значение свойства объекта с проверкой наличия ключа?

Tags: javascript, node.js

В каком-то примере видел получение значений свойств объекта в javascript в виде наподобие:

```
object.property?.property_2
```

Помогите найти документацию по этому способу.
Возможно это не JS, конечно...

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining

Answer (score 0, accepted):

такая запись `?.` называется [Optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) и позволяет упростить запись проверки на наличие свойств.